# What's the word for the study of ideology?

Tags: single-word-requests, suffixes

So ideology archaically means the study of ideas according to Google, but in modern times it means a system of ideas particularly for politics or economics despite still ending in -ology. Casually `ideologyology` gets the point across, but is there a better word for the study of ideologies? I thought of metaideology, but I think the meaning might not be clear.

Example sentence: "There is a book about < insert word >"

Comment: Isn't that broadly called _philosophy_?

Comment: This book is about how to analyze political ideologies.

Comment: If you were thinking that it might be _ideologyology_, beware. That way madness lies—as, for example, in calling "the study of geology" _geologyology_.

Answer (score 1):

There is the term ***political economy***:

> *Political economy* most commonly refers to interdisciplinary studies drawing upon economics, sociology, and political science in explaining how political institutions, the political environment, and the economic system — capitalist, socialist, communists, or mixed — influence each other.
>   <sub>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_economy)</sub>

If you want a broader term that includes more disciplines, you can consider ***social science***:

> **Social science** is a major category of academic disciplines, concerned with society and the relationships among individuals within a society. It in turn has many branches, each of which is considered a "social science". The main social sciences include economics, political science, human geography, demography, and sociology.
>   <sub>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_science)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Ideologies such as Marxism, Communism, Keynsian economics, Capitalism etc., are all theories. When you study theory itself, you are undertaking **Meta-theory**. This is quite a common term for what you are describing, and I have sat and taken modules at university in Meta-theory.